# Auto layout issue

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout, swift2

I have a UIButton inside a UIView sitting at the bottom of a UITableView (outside and after the tableViewCell), with the following constraints:

[image]

The result looks like this:

[image]

I can't figure out these:

1. How can I add extra space between the last cell and the button?
2. How can I have the bottom of the tableView (which is also the bottom of the phone screen itself) not hide part of the button's bottom side?

**** EDIT ****

X + Y constraints removed. Sign changed to positive. Now I get more space from the button which is good but the bottom part of the button is still hidden. It now looks like this:

[image]

And the latest result:

[image]

Comment: Why did you put the UIView inside the tableView?

Comment: Because I wanted to be able to resize the button width so that it's not taking the full view controller's width. I couldn't without embedding it in a UIView first,

Comment: That's fine, but it seems like the TableView is modifying the position of the view. As @jcaron states in a comment, "A view embedded in a tableview in IB is a table footer view." So, if you would like more control, you might consider creating a UIView that contains both the tableview and the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have clearly conflicting constraints, which you should see when clicking on the red-background arrow at the top right of your view hierarchy (and which gives all this red on the constraints).

Start by removing the constraints on centerX and centerY. Also your constraints constants seem to have the wrong sign.

Comment: X + Y constraints removed. Sign changed to positive. Now I get more space from the button which is good but the bottom part of the button is still hidden.

Comment: Just increase the size of the footer view. You may also want to add a constraint from the bottom of the button to the bottom of the footer view.

Comment: Can I explicitly link a constraint to the footer? I can't see the footer under the TableView on the storyboard. How can I do that?

Comment: Your view that contains the button is the footer. All the constraints shown in your screenshot are from the button to the footer.

Comment: Adding another constraint from the button's bottom to the bottom of the VC gives me a conflicting constraint

Comment: As I said, you need to adjust the footer's height.

Answer (score 0):

You can go two ways:
1) Separate bottom view and tableView, because now your bottom view placed like subview on tableview.
2) Make bottom view as tableview footer view: `self.tableView.tableFooterView`

Comment: A view embedded in a tableview in IB **is** a table footer view.

Comment: But how can I separate them?

Comment: What do you mean by separate? You can make footer height bigger than Send order button height, so you'll have some margin between cell and button - http://prntscr.com/9p8d23

Comment: Thx for the screenshot. How do I explicitly make the footer height bigger since I can't see it on the storyboard? Is it via code only? That's the bit I don't get.

Comment: You can setup any simulated size for your ViewController if something doesn't fit on the screen. To do it go to Attributes Inspector > Simulated Metrics > Size > Freeform http://prntscr.com/9pn8d9 . And after go to Size Inspector and setup height that will fit for you http://prntscr.com/9pn8od .

Answer (score 0):

Following @jcaron answer and @shpasta comments, I ended up increasing the height of UIView containing the button directly from the storyboard:

[image]

This solved the issue.

Thanks!